# div que não ultrapassa certos limites

Tags: jquery, css, menu

Bom, nesse link :: http://voky.com.ua/crostini/ existe um menu que ao carregar a pagina nao fica fixo no topo da tela, porém ao descer a pagina um pouco esse menu aparece  e fica fixo no topo. Como que se faz isso?

Comment: O seu título da pergunta não condiz muito com o que você está perguntando de fato. O ideal seria deixar o título mais claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplo online no [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gzmhw3m5/). Fiz um exemplo o mais limpo possível para permitir adaptação.

**<sub>HTML</sub>**

```
<div class="div1"></div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="div2"></div>
```

**<sub>JS</sub>**

```
$(function() {
    var offsetTop = $('#nav').offset().top;
    var navigation = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > offsetTop){
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        }else{
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        navigation();
    });
});
```

**<sub>CSS</sub>**

```
*{margin:0; border:0; padding:0; font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.div1{background:#669900; height:200px; width:100%}
.div2{background:#669900; height:700px; width:100%}

#nav{width:100%; height:50px; background:#fff;}
#nav ul{list-style:none; margin:0; padding:5px;}
#nav ul li{ margin:0; padding:0; display:inline; }
#nav ul li a{float:left; margin:0 5px; padding:0 10px; height:40px; line-height:40px; color:#fff; background:#333; text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: Perfeito. Exatamente o que eu queria.